# Change paperclip tmp files location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Is it possible to move the (`/tmp/stream*`) tempfiles generated by paperclip to another location like `/railsapp/public/tmp` without changing tmpfiles for the whole app environment? I would like to show a preview of the uploaded file if validation fails on the model.

Comment: Stream files are the 'internal cuisine' of the web server, as Slobodan  has shown in his answer. You shouldn't directly expose that to your users. More, once the request has ended, the web server can delete them, so you can't rely that on the next request(trying to display the image), they will still be there.

Comment: I only want to link to the stream* file if the form has failed validation. When the validation errors has been corected by the user and the model saved - I don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserving the uploads in Paperclip is such a hassle. However I ended up using this module: http://ryantownsend.co.uk/articles/storing-paperclip-file-uploads-when-validation-fails.html together with https://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart

Now you can do Ajax file uploads and preserve/preview the image if something fails.

Answer (score 2):

That's not Paperclip setting. It just uses file web server got from user.

You need to set this on web server level. If you are using Apache and Passenger you most likely want this setting:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_passengertempdir_lt_directory_gt

Comment: I am using nginx and thin.. hmmm I don't want to expose the entire temp dir to the world. Guess I could hardlink the paperclip tmp files to a dir in the public folder. (before_save) It's a bit strange that this can't be changed for paperclip with an option or parameter. :/

Comment: atmorell, files in tmp dir are, as the name says :), temporary. Web server gets them from user and puts them in tmp, where Rails/Paperclip can get them. Once you get them they should be moved somewhere - and Paperclip does this automatically.

As Vlad pointed out: Paperclip does not create /tmp/stream* files.

Not quite sure anymore what exactly you want to do and why.

Comment: Let's say a user submits a form and the validation fails. The form is preloaded with the data from the post form. The input/file field however is empty. What I am trying to do is give the user a preview of the file uploaded. The reason I was asking about moving the paperclip tmp files, is because I don't know if there is anything in the rais tmp dir that could be a security risk if moving the rails tmp dir to app/public/tmp

Comment: You would have to move file manually then. You cannot leave it in tmp dir because it might be already deleted when user makes a next request.

Comment: I got it working by linking the /tmp/stream* files to /public/tmp /filename from my controller. link is deleted when the model is saved/file changed.

Comment: @atmorell could you please elaborate on how you did that?